# How do I activate Ip tables or UFW with ease. Also, use elevation to activate

Tags: gufw

How do I activate Ip tables or UFW with ease. Also, use elevation to activate. Further once active how to I block all unsolicited incoming coneections and yet allow all outgoing connections

Answer (score 0):

At it's simplest, enable ufw with `sudo ufw enable` and enter your password. That's it. By default, it will block all incoming connections, but allow outgoing.

I prefer gufw as a graphical interface to ufw. Do `sudo apt-get install gufw` and then run the application from the Dash by searching for "firewall".